# PhpMyadmin problem intall

Tags: 12.04, phpmyadmin

when i try this command  : apt-get -y install phpmyadmin

i get this error :
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: ttf-dejavu-core but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: apache2 or
                          lighttpd but it is not going to be installed or
                          httpd

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to install other packages before you go ahead with your phpmyadmin install.

First install Apache server then afterwards try installing phpmyadmin.

[Apache Install Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Comment: i have already  install apach2 @Robert